# Does a school need to do Bedikas Chametz?

Tags: halacha, yeshiva-school, bedikas-chametz

Does a School need to do Bedikas Chametz?

What do Schools generally do?

I would think that it would be the responsibility of the Head of School to ensure that Bedikah is done.  Even if they were to sell the chametz, Bedikah should be done. 
However, in my limited experience I have not heard of schools doing Bedikah.  What is the solution that would allow them to not do it?

Comment: very closely related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15487/759

Answer (score 1):

General rule - if property is owned by a Jew, as is the case of just about every yeshiva that I know, then they must do bedikat chametz. IIRC, if one leaves the property more than 1 month before Pesach and will not be returning before then, no bedika is required. I can't say that this is what occurs in Israeli yeshivot. But in U.S. this is not the case, so a bedika is required.

A yeshiva down the block from me has dorm rooms. Students are responsible to clean their own rooms and share responsibility of the public shared spaces. Since they leave about 2 weeks before Pesach, they do bedika before they leave, from what I understand.

As for the rest of the yeshiva, there are public spaces used by the community all 385 days of this year (yes. The 385 is correct!) This includes kiddushim during Pesach, shalot se'idot twice this year during Pesach. I believe that the Rosh yeshiva does the bedika Erev Pesach. Point is, it needs to be chametz free.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know what local High Schools or Grade Schools do?

Comment: How do you know this rule?

Comment: Must mention but one still needs bittul. One can always sell the school over pesach and then one needn't do bedika either.

Comment: @RCW I don't want to reveal the exact area that I live in. But, within the New York City area, every yeshiva that I know of does this. Yeshiva University, I know, has pretty strict rules about both dorm clean up and locker room clean up. When my kid's were in elementary & high school (same building) they had to empty their desks and lockers **completely** which meant food, papers as well as books. I knew the head of maintenance, and I believe that he and his crew opened lockers, threw out leftovers and bleached and scoured all lockers, desks, blackboards, floors, and cubbies. Very thorough!

Comment: @DanF Yes, but did they come back the night before Pesach and do a Bedikah?

Comment: @newcomer Would the sale of the school be considered a Arama, an insincere sale?  How do they address that?

Comment: @RCW  See http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bedikat_Chametz#When One must do bedika prior to leaving the premises. So, students did this about 2 weeks before Pesach. The Rosh Yeshiva who lives in the neighborhood does it the night of 14 Nissan.

Comment: Every mchiras chomets is an insincere sale. @RCW.  See my other comments. They are not done in conformance with the kitsur either.  You must realise the chomets is not sold to the rabbi. So he has nothing to lose.  Although I wrote to sell the school or the chomets in it I did not really mean it.  There would be many problems of how to sell it.

Comment: @newcomer "Every mchiras chomets is an insincere sale.". I understand your sentiments. However, if you can get a hold of Rabbi Blumenkrantz's Pesach guide (doesn't have to be the latest one, but within say the last 5 years), he explains in good detail how and why this is a valid sale. In brief, it is similar to owning stocks. The owner never sees the actual item, yet it is certainly a valid ownership, as we all know. And all buying and selling is legal and involves actual finances moving around. Maybe during Hol Hamo'ed, I can get the book & scan it to a shared drive so you can access it.

Comment: They can only be valid if they are legal. I challenge any high court judge to state this sale is legal. @DanF. If one tried to force the goy to complete (he only pays deposit) no judge would ever force him.

Comment: @newcomer OK. I'm partially accepting the challenge. I am not a lawyer, but, B"N, I shall discuss the NY state legalities with my rav. In discussing this topic last week, he outright stated that the sale is a full legal sale according to NY state law. I'll see if I can discuss with him how he knows this. If I get an answer, I'll try to post this as a separate question with my own answer. My suggestion - OK to be skeptical, but, also be open other possibilities instead of dismissing it, outright. Happy Pesach.

Comment: Please also ask him why all rabbis today dismiss @DanF the kitsur who gives a different amount of deposit depending on the price.